# "Arnold raced out of the door": grammatical or not?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

> Arnold raced out of the door, and started...

In its time, it was once reported, this was one of the most often-read lines of fiction in the English language: it is the sentence fragment shown in a brief close-up shot of mystery novelist Jessica Fletcher's typewriter in the opening credits of *Murder, She Wrote* from 1984 to 1991.

Even conceding that "door" can be used as a perfectly legitimate synonym for "doorway," this always bothered me. One may race *out of* a room, and one may race *through* a doorway, but I don't see how Arnold could have raced *out of a door*—unless perhaps he had been standing still in the middle of the doorway before suddenly "racing" out of it, which seems unlikely.

What's interesting is that "Arnold raced out the door" doesn't bother me as much without the *of*, perhaps because I'm subconsciously putting an implied *through* into the sentence: "Arnold raced out [through] the door." Even so, I was surprised and amused to see that, out of all the examples they could have chosen, Merriam-Webster illustrates [its definition of *out* as a preposition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out?show=2) with the phrase "ran *out* the door." (Were the writers of this definition *Murder, She Wrote* fans, I wonder?) This doesn't seem to leave much room for my interpretation.

How should the clause "Arnold raced out of the door" be evaluated? Is it ungrammatical, grammatical but poor form, or grammatical with no reservations?

Comment: To me, as a native speaker, it seems perfectly grammatical on first read, but I'm unable to explain why (maybe it's because "out of the doorway" sounds fine, or just because a door sounds like something you can go *out* of; it doesn't have to be logical).

Comment: If you race through a room you are assuming that the room has no doors or they are all open.  If you race through a door, taking that literally, is impossible.  A door is too small for a child to fit into, so technically that is improper grammar.  But if you are assuming that the door is open (which is not specified in the small context that was given to me) then you could race through a door, because the absence of the door allows you to go through it, because more often than not it is closed.

Comment: Rethinking my previous comment, it is poor grammar because you have to make an assumption that a) the door is open, b) it's an expression, as if to say that he is running so fast that he practically runs through the door and c) he cannot fit in the door.  Of course these assumptions are relatively easy to make; the sentence itself should use "doorway" to make it easier to read and make the sentence dramatically correct without any possible chances of a different meaning.

Comment: Nowadays, the question would probably be 'adjusted' (in fact, I might do it myself) to 'Arnold raced out of the door': acceptable or not? 'Grammatical' doesn't involve decisions on word-choice. The question becomes "Is 'Arnold raced out of the door' an acceptable paraphrase of 'Arnold raced out through the doorway'?" And this is only answerable by looking at frequencies of use in varying registers. Certainly we use metonymy ('boil the kettle') and synecdoche ('he mustered 700 cavalry and 20 000 foot') with varying degrees of contentedness in varying registers ('foot' and 'wheels'!)

Comment: This is a psychological phenomenon where seeing something too often makes it seem weird, also seen eg if you repeat a common word enough. Not something to see a psychologist over but you should be aware. And stop dissing Jessica Fletcher.

Comment: You say 'Even conceding that "door" can be used as a perfectly legitimate synonym for "doorway," this always bothered me'. That is correct: they mean the same thing here. And "He's in the toilet" may or may mean "He's on the toilet" and something else again if your hopes go "down the toilet." Such is the nature of language. BTW, I would say "He raced out the door" without the "of."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following three sentences.

1. He raced out the door.
2. He raced out of the doorway.
3. He raced out of the door.

In the first sentence *out* is a preposition [meaning](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/out?region=us) 'through to the outside'. This is entirely unproblematic: he was in a room or building, and he raced out of it through the door(way).

In formal English the second sentence is equally clear: *out* is an adverb meaning 'moving or appearing to move away from a particular place, especially one that is enclosed', and the sentence means that he raced out of the doorway in which he had been standing. I shouldn’t be at all surprised, however, to find that some people use it synonymously with (1).

Since 'doorway' is one perfectly standard [meaning](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/door?region=us) of *door*, and since it is more than a little difficult to stand in a physical door, (3) is formally synonymous with (2). However, many people, evidently including at least one writer for *Murder, She Wrote*, use it synonymously with (1). For those people *out of* has in effect become a compound preposition meaning 'through to the outside' as well as the combination of adverb and preposition found in the formal interpretation of (2). I suspect that this, like *in back of* for *behind*, is more common in the US than in the UK. In the US, at least, it’s common enough to qualify as normal English, though there are also speakers like me who would never use it because it’s ungrammatical in their idiolects.

Answer (score 9):

I think this is a job for Google Ngrams.

Google Ngrams shows that in 1900, *out of the door* was the expression both in the U.S. and the U.K. But the majority of Americans switched from using *out of the door* to *out the door* [around 1940](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=out+the+door%3Aeng_us_2019%2Cout+the+door%3Aeng_gb_2019%2Cout+of+the+door%3Aeng_us_2019%2Cout+of+the+door%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), and now *out of the door* is quite rare. This same switch wasn't made in the U.K. until 1990. So I would guess *out of the door* sounds funny to many Americans, but both expressions sound perfectly fine to U.K. speakers (except maybe for traditionalists trying futilely to stop the language from evolving).

I believe the choice between these expressions is idiomatic, and trying to analyze which to use with pure reason is not going to yield worthwhile results.

Comment: As [this](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=out+the+window%2Cout+of+the+window&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) one shows, the word *"of"* has also been dropped from *"out the window"*. Though it seems to be a bit later, in that the crossover to dominance didn't happen until the early 70s, about 30 years after that happened with *"door"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: *"out of the window"* still seems to be more common [in the U.K.](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=out+the+window%2Cout+of+the+window&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=6&smoothing=5) although this may not last for much longer. The difference in crossover time is at least partly due to the unexplained fact that the expression *out (of) the door* is much rarer in the U.K.

Answer (score 4):

As [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=out+of+the+door%2Cout+the+door&year_start=1800&year_end=1985&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows, over the last half-century, *"out the door"* has displaced the previously-preferred *"out* **of** *the door"*.
[image]

I didn't include the most recent 20 years or so, because the new form is now so common that would distort the vertical scale, so you'd hardly notice the 'crossover point' around 1940. But as you can see [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=out+of+the+door%2Cout+the+door&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), that red line just keeps going up at the same rate.

I doubt there's really any meaningful *reason* for the change - it's really just a matter of style. But most people today don't often hear the older form, so it seems 'strange' to them when they do.

---

I think the issue of whether or not it's "grammatical" is really just pedantry. Firstly, there are hundreds of thousands of written instances of [ran out of the door](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22ran%20out%20of%20the%20door%22&oq=%22ran%20out%20of%20the%20door%22&gs_l=serp.3...4817278.4825629.7.4826117.33.33.0.0.0.0.102.1703.32j1.33.0...0.0...1c.1.5.serp.-g9qkU53BMw&psj=1&biw=1320&bih=897&cad=cbv&sei=fC01UYChOcio0AWtjYDIAQ); any rule of grammar debarring such a commonplace usage would surely be flawed. Secondly, it's not obvious to me how any such rule could be phrased to avoid also finding fault with [jumped out of the window](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22ran%20out%20of%20the%20door%22&oq=%22ran%20out%20of%20the%20door%22&gs_l=serp.3...4817278.4825629.7.4826117.33.33.0.0.0.0.102.1703.32j1.33.0...0.0...1c.1.5.serp.-g9qkU53BMw&psj=1&biw=1320&bih=897&cad=cbv&sei=fC01UYChOcio0AWtjYDIAQ#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22jumped%20out%20of%20the%20window%22&oq=%22jumped%20out%20of%20the%20window%22&gs_l=serp.3...354780.362413.0.362669.19.19.0.0.0.0.123.1166.17j2.19.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.KLEj5NXY7rQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43148975,d.d2k&fp=7887a906c76385b1&biw=1320&bih=897) (where I'm interested to see the tendency to discard "of" is much more recent, and [less pronounced](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jumped%20out%20the%20window,jumped%20out%20of%20the%20window&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Answer (score 3):

The NOAD has the following notes about using *out of*, or *out*:

> The use of *out* as a preposition (rather than the standard prepositional phrase *out of*), as in "he threw it out the window," is common in informal contexts, and is standard in American, Australian, and New Zealand English. Traditionalists do not accept it as part of standard British English, however.

The phrase, whatever it uses *out of* or *out*, is grammatically correct; in both the cases, the phrase is standard in American English, but the standard British English phrase is the one using *out of*.

Answer (score 2):

'Out' for 'out of' - common with 'door' and 'window', but less so in other phrases. For example, I have never heard 'out sight, out mind' or 'out pity'. Perhaps in the future such usage will not be 'out the question'.

Comment: And even *out the door* is commoner in the US than elsewhere.

Comment: @TimLymington: Ron's answer here just prompted me to edit my own question, but I never thought to compare UK/US corpuses. You're quite right - the move to discard "of" is indeed primarily American-led.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatical? Certainly! Just the way ["Colorless green ideas sleep furiously"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously) is grammatical, or they way "Arnold raced out of an electron" is grammatical. Grammaticality has to do with how the rules of a language allow the constituents of a sentence to come together.

Coming to the phrases you wrote, scientists and lawyers may sometimes need to split hairs and make distinctions between such phrases, but usually, we find such phrases acceptable and equivalent because of [conversational implicatures](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/implicature/).

Answer (score 0):

> but I don't see how Arnold could have raced out of a door—unless perhaps he had been standing still in the middle of the doorway before suddenly "racing" out of it, which seems unlikely.

Apart from the comment being rather pedantic, this construction is, in fact, very clear.

We agree that "out" is an adverb "in an outwards direction"

Compare the Old English of = contextually associated with; from, off, away from.

In all of these, (ignoring the possessive which is not germane here) an origin is indicated:

Robin of/from Loxley - Robin was born (or had his origins) in Loxley;

The knife is made of/from steel; Some steel was the origin of the knife.

he took a seed off/from/of the tree. - the seed had its origins on the tree.

**Of** has a very complicated origin which the OP should research, but basically, in Old English, **of** and **off** were the same word, differentiated by emphasis only, and **from** bore a similarity in that it indicated an origin.

The word "**of**" was further complicated by being used to translate the French-Norman (and modern French) "de", which itself is of multiple origins.

Compare:
he took a seed **off/from/of** the tree. -> il a pris une graine **de** l'arbre.

Comparer also the Modern German "von" and "of" and "from": Klaus **von** Bulow = Charles **of/from** Bulow

In "He ran out of the door" - He ran in an outwards direction [and he ran] from the door.

If an alternative is required then the OED describes "out of" as a preposition in itself:

> **I.3.a. From a place, person, or thing as a source, origin, or provenance; deriving from**

1871 He should get money out of the Greeks before he assisted them. *B. Jowett in translation of Plato, Dialogues vol. II. 29*

> **I.1.b. Indicating direction: from within, so as to point, project, or lead away from.**
>
> 1981 There were four or five other cells opening out of the passage. *G. Household, Summon Bright Water i. 11*

Answer (score 0):

If he can come *in* the door, he can go *out* the door.

I don't like *out **of** the door*, however, as **of** conveys the sense of a place of origin, as you say, "out of *the room*".

But people say what they say.

Comment: 'If he can come in the door, he can go out the door' is specious. 'If a book can be on top of a pile, it can be *on bottom of a pile.' (Note that 'on the bottom of ...' _is_ grammatical.) / 'If a person can be in a room, she can be *out a room.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What's specious is your counterexample,  "on top **of**", which is more complicated as a result of "of".

Comment: Moreover, I gave the example of binary opposite verbs of motion:  "come in/go out". Your generalization ignores that.

Comment: Saying B is incorrect doesn't refute 'A is incorrect'. // Would you use 'go out the car'?

Comment: So, let me get this right. You are saying that with two verbs of motion, which have opposite meanings (e.g. go, come) and two prepositions which mean the opposite (e.g. in, out), if the one combination is possible with a given noun phrase (e.g. go in the door) that is no guarantee of the grammaticality of the inverse, (e.g. go out the door), when the verbs of motion are used *qua* verbs of motion and not figuratively? (A figurative use would be one like "Let me run this up the chain of command").  If that is a fair statement of your position, do you have an example?

Comment: Using 'come' literally:  'Come in the light' is used in the UK as a shortened form of 'Come into the light [where you can see]'; 'Go out the light', I'd say, is unknown (and only false-positives appear in a Google search). / The whole question here is about the use of the shortening of the compound preposition 'out of' (cf the closed compound 'into') to 'out', and the limitations affecting idiomaticity. apaderno mentions geographical differences, Ron Short complement restrictions ('door'; 'window'), and Peter Shor changes in usage over time. Arguments from analogy are often shaky and need ...

Comment: to be supported by cited research.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=come+in+the+light%2Ccome+out+the+light%2Cstep+into+the+light%2Cstep+out+of+the+light&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3