# Omission of the word “to”

Tags: prepositions

Following is an excerpt from Michelle Dean's post in [The Newyorker](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/culture/2013/03/a-note-on-nerdfighters.html) (my emphasis):

> “One of the reasons Hank and I have always resisted being on television is that we don’t really want nerdfighters to be a mainstream cultural phenomenon,” **Green wrote me**. “I worry that mainstream cultural phenomena need, like, Message Singularity and A Brand and an Institutional Voice and stuff. That kind of thing does not interest us at all. We just want to make cool stuff with people we like.

Has the writer omitted *to* when she writes *Green wrote me*?

Comment: 1. Yes, the writer has omitted *to* in that clause. 2. Such omissions are commonplace. 3. The elision of normally expected words that can be supplied by context is called *ellipsis*.

Comment: Check out the examples under Def. #2 in [this dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/write) – particularly the one about poor Simon! Because _write_ can mean _write (a letter) to_, the _to_ isn't always needed.

Comment: This is not ellipsis. "Green wrote me" is perfectly acceptable English. "Green spoke me" is not. This is because the verb "write" is doubly transitive (and so can have both an indirect object and a direct object), while "speak" is not.

Comment: Related (though seen from the other side): http://english.stackexchange.com/q/39765/8019

Answer (score 2):

From the ODO's entry for [write](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/write):

> **chiefly North American** write and send a letter to:
>   *Mother **wrote me** and told me about poor Simon’s death*

As the definition notes, such usage is peculiar to the American audience of *The New Yorker*. It's perfectly fine in AmE, but will probably raise an eyebrow if used elsewhere.