# "Stormed out the room" or "Stormed out of the room"

Tags: grammar

A friend and I were talking about this, and she was telling me it's incorrect to say, for instance, "Joe stormed out the room." According to her, one would say,"Joe stormed out of the room." Do both work or only the latter? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The **of** is necessary—at least if you don't want people giving you funny looks when you omit it.

Comment: "Joe stormed out the room" is just wrong.

Comment: As I see it, there are three possibilities: **1** "Joe stormed the room." – this would mean that Joe (and some friends) attacked the room with force and fury. **2** "Joe stormed out the room." – **out** is an adverb; **to storm out** is an intransitive phrasal verb; **the room** is a complement. **3** "Joe stormed out of the room." – **out** is an adverb; **to storm out** is a phrasal verb, **of the room** is an adverbial, prepositional modifier.

Comment: @Greybeard *Storm out* **could** be a transitive phrasal verb, much as *clear out.* Perhaps it might mean "trashed the room as with a storm." Whatever the semantics, it's a validly grammatical interpretation.

Comment: In American English, you can *storm out the door*, but not *out the room*. [See this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39765/arnold-raced-out-of-the-door-grammatical-or-not).

Comment: In British English you can't even storm out the door. We say "storm out **of** the door"

Comment: I'm sure people _do_ say 'out the door', 'out the window' etc. in casual speech, but it is grammatically wrong.